# How should I store a frequently accessed array with an unknown number of elements in mongodb?

Tags: array, mongodb, list

I have a simple "Index" object defined as follows:

```
{
  "position": 4,
  "value": 345
}
```

And I'm trying to figure out the best way to store this object in a mongo database, assuming that:

- The "position" of each Index is not necessarily unique and does not depend on other Index objects
- Each user can have a huge number of Index objects associated with it (up to 5000), and the database has a huge number of users (more than 100k)
- The data is (very) frequently read and updated

What would be the best way to store these objects? The current implementation uses arrays, which is terribly inefficient for users with a low number of Index objects but wide gaps between positions (such as position 5 and position 1623). Should I use JSON objects? Lists?

Comment: This question belongs to stackoverflow

Comment: @StackManaged I'm not looking for an implementation, I'm looking for an approach